# JSRender loop through fields

Tags: javascript, jsrender

I try to create a (for me) complex template (form). My data is like this

```
var fields = [
        { name: "field1", type: "text", label: "Name" },
        { name: "field2", type: "text", label: "Address" },
        { name: "field3", type: "date", label: "Birth date" }
    ];
```

My template (part of it) is like this:

```
        <form id="EditForm">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>
                {{for}}
                <td>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for={{>name}}>{{>label}}</label>
                        <input type={{>type}} class="form-control" id={{>name}}>
                    </div>

                </td>
                {{/for}}
 ... etc...
```

I tried some different things but it is looks like it is not looping all my field.

I use jsREnder like this:

```
<div id="test"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#test").html(
        $("#UpdateTemplate").render(fields, true)
    );
</script>
```

Comment: can you share how you are using jsrender

Comment: Added that in the original post. Thanks

Comment: I changed my code. It is working now. Just had to do a "for" without adding a field

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code. It is working now. Just had to do a "for" without adding a field